# I am not able to import database content into my html file although there are no errors, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, visual-studio-code

I have a registration form which has the following fields (forms.py file):

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, IntegerField, PasswordField, SubmitField, TextAreaField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    fname = StringField("First Name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    lname = StringField("Last Name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo("password")])
    phoneno = StringField("Phone Number", validators=[DataRequired()])
    account_type = SelectField("Account Type", choices=[("User","User"), ("Driver","Driver")])
    submit = SubmitField("Sign Up")


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField("Rememeber Me")
    submit = SubmitField("Login")
```

now I have created a database which saves this data.
I now wish to display it on my app i.e display the first name that the user enters in their registration form, on the top of their app, etc. Here is the main code for that:

```
{% extends "admin-layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1>Your Profile</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5>First Name</h5>
        <h5>Last Name</h5>
        <h5>Email</h5>
        <h5>Phone no.</h5>
        <h5>Age</h5>
        <h5>{{fname}}</h5>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

As you can see I have used `{{fname}}` (which comes from the fname in my `forms.py`, to display the first name the have entered. I have imported:

```
from flaskapp.forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
```

in my `__init__.py` file mind you.

Now the issue is, it just doesnt work, there's no error, but I don't see the first name I have entered either eventhough everything else seems fine (`fname` doesnt work).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

here Is where I render my files:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
    <div>
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class = "container">
                <div class = "row">
                    
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 align-self-center">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                Register
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div>
                                    {{ form.hidden_tag()}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.fname, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.lname, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.email, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.phoneno, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.password, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.confirm_password, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.account_type, class="form-control")}}
                                    
                                    {{ render_field(form.submit, class="btn btn-primary")}}
                                </div>
                                <a href="{{ url_for('auth.login')}}">Login</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock app_content %}
```

Comment: Have you created a route for this html file? Have you passed fname in the render command? Can you add this part of the code in your question?

Comment: @archer I have added the code where I render the fname in the register.html file. What do you mean by 'route for your html file'?